# AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token). Despite all trials this error continues to pop

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an app for a tic tac toe game using android studio . But it's showing this error .
I am unable to find any mistake in this xml code. Until now i have not written any code in main activity . This didnt worked in this phase itself. I am a beginner in android development

Here's my entire code.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:rowCount="3"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"
            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"
            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp

            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"

            android:layout_margin="11dp"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"

            android:layout_margin="11dp"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"

            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"

            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"

            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="106dp"
            android:layout_height="106dp"

            android:layout_margin="11dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />


    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide any error message/stacktrace. Without error we really cant do anything, and you will receive low quality answers

Comment: Please show the stack trace so we can help

Answer (score 1):

forget ["].

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="106dp" //add here ["]
    android:layout_margin="11dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/greengoti" />
```